# Clustering data to recover individual functions of a lower-hemicontinuous correspondence/bifurcation diagram

Tags: algorithms, clustering, mathematical-analysis, numerical-analysis

I have a data (from simulations) that is coming from something similar to a bifurcation diagram: it is a lower hemicontinuous correspondence (actually limit points of each branch is included), or in other words a set-valued function mapping a point in the domain to a (non-empty) set in the codomain such that the set is the union of the images of a finitely-many (scalar/vector-valued) continuous functions under that point. The scalar/vector-valued functions are defined over the convex subsets of the domain. Thus the graph is a union of graphs of finitely-many continuous functions defined over subsets of the domain. To express myself better, consider this implication: I can make a selection (by selecting a single element from the set-valued image for each point in the domain) so that the selection would correspond to a piecewise function of finitely many continuous functions. Of course there are usually more than one possible selections.

I would like to cluster the data so that each cluster corresponds to one such (scalar/vector-valued) function. I don't necessarily need an approximation of the function (although that would be a great bonus), but just to identify curves/surfaces that are images of these functions.

The reason I can't immediately use some standard clustering algorithms is that I have the following constraint: each cluster should be an image of a function, or in other words in each cluster there cannot be two elements whose "domain" component is identical.

I would appreciate any suggestions/comments. I would be happy to clarify any parts that are not very clear.

Comment: Can you formulate your question with mathematics rather than words?  I am having a hard time understanding the problem statement.